# white screen is appearing before a webpage loads in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, html

I have an ipad app(basically a magazine) all the contents(text/images/css/js) are loading from server(all html pages), when the app downloads locally, and when i make a transition or swipe to next pages, a WHITE SCREEN IS APPEARING and then the content is loading. iOS version is 4.2

Comment: so what is it that you want to do..? load before it appears?

Comment: if yes then post your .m file.

Comment: yeah i mean the rendering must be smooth, there shouldn't be any white screen appearing on the webview.

Comment: Hi the number of lines exceeding than the limit, can you share your email id so that i can mail you the code

Comment: try whatever you are doing in viewdidload and wait till webviewdidfinishloading is called.. that will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you represent your "pages" but basically, when you display a page, you have to load the next one to prevent the lag you are currently seeing.

So, when you display the n-th page, it has already been loaded when you displayed the n-1-th, and you load the n+1-th.

Ankit gave you the delegate method to track when your UIWebView is loaded.